# Trying to make a pow() calculator, without the pow, ERROR message "'int' object has no attribute 'count'"

Tags: python

The idea is, that the calculator is supposed to detect the numbers of num1 in the calculation and add more until it is equal to the num2, as it is supposed to be num1 raised to the power of num2.

But I keep receiving this message "'int' object has no attribute 'count'". I know the count is for lists, so I was wondering, what the appropriate command would be for int (or float).

Furthermore, how would I go about adding the numbers of "num1" to the equation?

Here is the whole code

```py
num1 = int(input("Enter a number"))
operator = input("Now enter an operator")
num2 = int(input("Enter a new number"))
Pow = (num1*num1)
if operator == "^":
    print(Pow)
    while Pow.count(num1) < num2 += 1:
         Pow = num1 * num1
```

Comment: well you can't `count` on an int, so yea

Comment: `while Pow.count(num1) < num2 += 1:` I have no idea how you expect this to work. I don't know what you mean by "the appropriate command would be for int (or float)"; what exactly do you think `.count` does for lists, and what are you trying to do for the int that's similar?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you were trying to track how many times you multiplied your result by `num1`. If you want to use a `while` loop, the only option is to introduce a separate variable `count` and increase it `count+=1` inside the while loop. On a separate note, it does not make sense to repeat `Pow=num1*num1` if your num1 is constant.

Comment: @Karl Knetchel

I am trying to count the numbers of num1, as this represents a static value,e ntered at the very beginning of the script, so therefore - without much knowledge about Python or code language in particular - I assume it should be countable?

The idea is, as I explained in my reply to Teku, to make a sort-of pow() function, where the loop repeats itself until the number of num1's + num1 is equal to the value of num2, as the value of num2 is the value, the user whiches to lift num1 to the power of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
operator = input("Now enter an operator: ")
num2 = int(input("Enter a new number: "))
goal = num1 ** num2
#print("goal: " + str(goal))
count = 1

if operator == '^':
    while num1 < goal:
        #print(num1)
        num1 += num1
        count += 1
    #print(num1)
    print ("It took %(count)d loops to get to %(num)d!" % {'count': count, 'num':  goal})
```

Your question is vague, but I believe this is what you are looking for?

## Edited code above and included example below

[image: working example]

Comment: Hello Teku,

Thank you for your answer, and I am sorry if I have been to vague.

The idea is, that it is supossed to count how many num1's there are, and then add num1's untill, there are as many num1s equalling the value of num2. As this is meant to represent x (num1) ^ y (num2).

For example, let us say num1 = 2 and num2 = 4, it would take 5 num1's for the equation to be 2^4, therefore it must loop until the number of num1's == value of num2.

- I know the pow() function exists, but I am not doing this for practicality as much as curiosity.

Comment: I think I understand now, is the above code more along the correct lines now? @GeorgeWTrump

Answer (score 0):

You have an `Invalid Syntax` here which is `while Pow.count(num1) < num2 += 1:`

Have a look at this edited code:

```py
num1 = int(input("Enter a number"))
operator = input("Now enter an operator")
num2 = int(input("Enter a new number"))
Pow = (num1*num1)
if operator == "^":
    print(Pow)
    while num1 < num2:
        Pow = num1 * num1
        num2 += 1
```

Comment: Hello Ahmed,

Thank you for your reply,

The idea is that it is supossed to count the amounts of num1's not the entered value of num1, so that it can become a sort-of pow() function.

I have described this in more detail in my previous answer, but none the less, thank you for your attempt :)